# Node.js post request not executing callback

Tags: node.js

So ive got this function:

```
async function getRandomNumber(){
    const https = require('https');

    const url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke';

    const params:object = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "generateIntegers",
        "params": {
            "apiKey": process.env.randomApiKey,
            "n": 1,
            "min": 1,
            "max": 10,
        },
        "id": 42
    }

    const options = {
        hostname: 'https://api.random.org',
        port: 443,
        path: '/json-rpc/2/invoke',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(params))
        }
      };

      const req =  https.request(options, (res:any) => {
        console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk:any) => {
          console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
      });

      req.on('error', (e:any) => {
        console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
      });

      // Write data to request body
      req.write(JSON.stringify(params));
      req.end();
}
```

which is being called like this:

```
await getRandomNumber();
```

But the call back does not log anything, so it seem that the post request is not beeing executed? How can I make this work?

Is it better to use the request module?

Comment: How are you calling this? can you show that also?

Comment: And yes, I would prefer using the request module any time over anything else while making outgoing requests from your node app

Comment: It is shown in the question: await getRandomNumber();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to await a callback style function which doesn't return a promise. You need to return a promise to await it.

Regarding request module, i wouldn't suggest using it as it is not maintained. You can read more here

https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

This also talks about alternative libraries

https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143

One of the library is `got` which can simplify the work which are doing. the code will look like

```
const getResponse = await got("http://someurlhere");

console.log(getResponse.body);
```

Comment: Yes i fixed by wrapping the post function in a promise. Then awating for he promise to be completed. Thanks for the info!